# Sockets and items

Tags: dota-2

I have a couple of questions about item socketing.

1. What is the effect of Bloodstone in the process of socketing? I have Bloodstone of the Founder,does it have any other effects compared to the other Bloodstone qualities?
2. How many sockets an item could have at maximum?
3. Can I create sockets on all items or are there limitation?

Answer (score 1):

1. The bloodstone will add **Ascendant** prefix to your item and will change the item name color to red.
   Alongside the gifts granted stat counter to show off how many beta keys you gave away.

   When socketed all bloodstones look the same only difference is in the number of gifts and the name of the gem  itself.
2. An Item can have 5 sockets at maximum.
3. Sockets can be created on all items even on couriers.

For more information read this [guide on socketing and crafting](http://www.dotacinema.com/news/a-guide-to-socketing-and-crafting)!